# Cross-axis size for vertical flexbox after image shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a  layout with some text (or possibly other stuff) underneath an image and the combination of text and image having a fixed height. The code below does that, but the flexbox container doesn't update its width after the image has been scaled down (stays at 600 pixels). How do I get the container to be only as wide as the image?

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/600'>
  <span>Some text</span>

</div>
```

I am looking for something like this, but without specifying the height of the text or the height the image:

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}

span {
  height: 20px;
}

img {  
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/600'>
  <span>Some text</span>

</div>
```

Edit: If possible, any potential solution should also include a way to add a link to the image.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a image it will automaticly put the height but you have to put the height there.
you could put padding on the top and bottom if you realy dont want to use height.